# How to get column data from a row in postgresSQL?

Tags: sql, pivot, postgresql-9.1

I have a database table name payroll like

| Employee | Period | Attributes | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Zakir | Oct'18 | Basic | 20000 |
| Zakir | Oct'18 | H.Rent | 10000 |
| Zakir | Oct'18 | Convene | 2000 |
| Zakir | Oct'18 | Medical | 2000 |
| Tame | Oct'18 | Basic | 30000 |
| Tame | Oct'18 | H.Rent | 15000 |
| Tame | Oct'18 | Convene | 2500 |
| Tame | Oct'18 | Medical | 2500 |

I want like

| Employee | Period | Basic | H.Rent | Convene | Medical | Gross |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Zakir | Oct'18 | 20000 | 10000 | 2000 | 2000 | 34000 |
| Tame | Oct'18 | 30000 | 15000 | 2500 | 2500 | 50000 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use case when

```
select employee ,period,
sum(case when attribute='basic' then amount else 0 end) basic,
sum(case when attribute='H.Rent' then amount else 0 end H_Rent,
sum(case when attribute='Convene' then amount else 0 end) Convene,
sum(case when attribute='Medical' then amount else 0 end) Medical,
sum(case when attribute='basic' then amount else 0 end)+
sum(case when attribute='H.Rent' then amount else 0 end)+
sum(case when attribute='Convene' then amount else 0 end)+
sum(case when attribute='Medical' then amount else 0 end) as gross
from payroll group by employee ,period
```